# CentOS Server file permissions

Tags: centos, files, apache-httpd, selinux

I am starting to learn server management with a CentOS Virtual Machine. I am trying to make a simple website.

Because the Apache default file is in `/var/www` it is hard to write/make/change files. Having said that, I would like to make the home page in the folder `/var/www` and all other pages will be in the folder `/home/$USER/Documents/Website`.

The code on the home page is just an `href` to the other pages.  When I run the code on the machine, it works, but if I go the the home page (type in the IP in a browser) the link doesn't work, but the home page is still there.

The error that I get when I click the link is `404 file not found`.

If I copy the file location from that error code and, on the Server, and type

```
cat {file_location}
```

It prints the file no problem.  I have changed the Apache group to the owner of the file. How can I allow the Apache server to find the files in here? Would I need to edit the `http.conf`?

EDIT:
How would I just make it so the server could read and write in a folder called `/Website`?

EDIT 2:
I do not know which version of Apache I am running.  I used the CentOS installer to install the Apache.  The `/var/www/html/index.html` is the webpage pulled up when I type in the IP address, as it should.  It very well could be a SELinux problem as after I installed the Server with GUI packages, a  SELinux pop-up told me of a 'security' problem.  I ran the scripts that it said and I could write the the `/var/www/html` folder.  Now I am wanting to add folders in a different location and I don't know how to do so.  Other than SELinux being in the way of writing to the `/var/www/html` folder, I also changed owner and ran `chmod 755` if I remember correctly.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What kind of Apache configuration are you using? What `DocumentRoot` is used there?

Comment: Initially I would recommend you take the easier route of learning how to set permissions to allow you to create/edit files under `/var/www`. Really. If you care to _extend_ your question to permit that as an acceptable alternative then someone here (if not me) can explain about `chmod`.

Comment: This could be an selinux problem as well, which would be far more complicated than simple file permissions. Its been my experience that if selinux is enabled and enforcing, then placing httpd content anywhere outside of normal locations results in a 404 unless you also update your selinux policies.

Comment: You still haven't provided any details on your Apache configuration?  What do you mean by "home page is just an href to the other pages."? Are you using `mod_userdir` for example? Why do you think server can't read/write to `/var/www/html` (what have you tried)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want Apache to serve files in `/Website`, edit your Apache configuration `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and change `DocumentRoot` to `/Website`. Then reload the server `systemctl reload httpd.service`.

You also need to change SELinux file context of `/Website` and files within. You likely want to use same file contexts as in `/var/www` (`httpd_sys_content_t` or `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`). Add new file labeling rule with `semanage` and then use `restorecon` to apply it:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/Website(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v /Website
```

---

If you want to configure Apache to serve user content in home directories, eg.  `http://server/~user`, you can use *mod_userdir*. Enable it in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf` and reload the server.

Enable `httpd_read_user_content` SELinux boolean to allow access:

```
semanage boolean -m --on httpd_read_user_content
```

Files in directory `public_html` should already be configured in correct `httpd_user_content_t` type. If not, you can run `restorecon -R -v /home/user/public_html` to apply correct file contexts.